# Set avatar image using layer atlas sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm working on sample to try chatting application using layer and atlas sdk, ive downloaded the sample from github , and i want for each user to set their avatar from the app. so it shows while chatting.

The app i'm trying to edit is using method to generate avatar depends on the name of the user but i don't want that.

The Class im editing is `ATLMUser` :

```
- (NSString *)avatarInitials
{
    NSMutableString *initials = [NSMutableString new];
    NSString *nameComponents = [self.fullName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *names = [nameComponents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if (names.count > 2) {
        NSString *firstName = names.firstObject;
        NSString *lastName = names.lastObject;
        names = @[firstName, lastName];
    }
    for (NSString *name in names) {
        [initials appendString:[name substringToIndex:1]];
    }
    return initials;
}
```

There exist methods in the class to set image but its returning nil like :

```
- (UIImage *)avatarImage
{
    return nil;
}

- (NSURL *)avatarImageURL
{
    return nil;
}
```

How can i edit the class to make each object set his own avatar.

Check out the sample here :https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement those methods you mention. Here’s an example of my implementation:

```
- (NSURL *)avatarImageURL
{
    if (self.avatar && (id)self.avatar != [NSNull null]) {
        return [NSURL URLWithString:self.avatar];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This assumes your user class has an avatar property with the URL to the image. If you’re still using Atlas provided back-end to authenticate users, you should switch to your own if you want to have full control over this.

Lastly, make sure you’re setting your ConversationListViewController to display avatars. I added this on `viewDidLoad`

`[self setDisplaysAvatarItem:YES];`

Comment: How do you set a default avatar for group conversations?

Comment: @T.Rex Your `ConversationListViewController` should implement `ATLConversationListViewControllerDataSource` protocol. Take a look at the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Atlas/1.0.0/Protocols/ATLConversationListViewControllerDataSource.html#//api/name/conversationListViewController:avatarItemForConversation:). Also check [this example](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-Messenger-iOS/blob/4b6ab70dfd62f6de3aadc5774b146d670c17df0f/Code/Controllers/ATLMConversationListViewController.m#L111).

Comment: @T.Rex You can do something similar to the example I linked to. Look for the number of participants, if it's a group return your default avatar. It should conform to the [ATLAvatarItem](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Atlas/1.0.1/Protocols/ATLAvatarItem.html) protocol.